# How to Get the List of Students whose Name Starts and Ends with the Same Character in a Single Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 SELECT 
      StudentName 
 FROM tblStudents 
      WHERE StudentName LIKE 'a%' AND StudentName LIKE '%a'
```

I am getting the list of records whose letter starts with specific character A, but i am not able to get the list of all the students from the letter A to Z.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT StudentName FROM tblStudents WHERE LEFT(StudentName,1)= RIGHT(StudentName,1)
```

Comment: This is going to go +10 fast :)

Answer (score 0):

TRy this one

> SELECT StudentName FROM tblStudents
>   WHERE SUBSTRING([StudentName ], 1, 1) = SUBSTRING([StudentName ], -1);

it will work

Comment: it returns you name start and end with same letter

Comment: But only the ones with a first and last, not b - z.

Comment: But that does only mean the name starts with a letter a - z and ends with another letter a - z, no guarantee at all it's the same letter. Take a look at mmhasabnnn's solution instead!

Comment: have u tried above ans     ya its working   use that